# Where is the sign conversion occurring?

Tags: c++, gcc, casting, warnings, sign

I have the following code:

```
unsigned int x, last_x;
int dx;
[...]
dx = x - last_x;
```

Compiling this with g++ (4.7.2) and -Wsign-conversion produces the following:
`warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘unsigned int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]`

The only way to make the warning disappear is by changing to:

```
dx = static_cast<int>(x) - static_cast<int>(last_x);
```

or

```
dx = static_cast<int>(x - last_x);
```

What is the explanation for this behaviour? Is the `-` operator only defined for signed ints? I would expect to have a `-` operator that takes unsigned values and returns a signed value.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with gcc 4.8.2, which gcc version did you use ?

Comment: The first cast (static_cast<int>(x - last_x)) gives no warning (g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2)

Comment: @DanNestor Then I suppose this is a gcc defect that has been fixed. Can you reproduce it even with this minimal sample: http://ideone.com/oI8pdD , compile with g++ -c -Wall -Wsign-conversion test.cpp ?

Comment: Yes, I reproduced this with a minimal sample. Note some edits to the question though.

Comment: What meaningful value can `dx` hold when `last_x == 0 && x == UINT_MAX `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operations on `unsigned int`s will result in `unsigned int`s. Even the subtraction will yield an `unsigned int`. the value just wraps around: unlike signed integer arithmetic, overflow and underflow for unsigned values results in well define behavior: the arithmetic is simply modulus `N` where `N` is one plus the maximum value which can be represented by the unsigned integer.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the type of `x - last_x` is unsigned int? Why doesn't `static_cast<int>(x - last_x)` work, then?

Comment: My mistake, it seems that `static_cast`ing the whole expression does indeed work.

Comment: @DanNestor: well, if `x < last_x` the result is a large `unsigned int` value which gets changed into a negative value. That is, the result changes its sign and gcc calls attention to that fact. Personally, I don't think it should warn when using `static_cast<int>(...)` explicitly but that is a decision up to the compiler implementers.

Comment: Actually, it does not warn if casting explicitly. It was a mistake I made. Thanks for clarifying that the result will overflow even when assigned to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is warning you that the statement you entered, `dx = x - last_x;`, could result in an unintended sign change.  That means when you execute `x - last_x`, which will be a positive number, when you convert it to a `int` and store it in `dx` the value may become negative.

Consider changing `unsigned int x, last_x;` to `int x, last_x;`.

Comment: changing to (int)(x - last_x) does *not* remove the warning.

Comment: Also, dx cannot be changed to unsigned. Consider that x and last_x represent coordinates, and dx is allowed to be negative.

Comment: I made a mistake though, your cast suggestion actually works.

Comment: @DanNestor It's still a problem though. :-(

Answer (score 1):

The warning is trying to warn you that things can go wrong! Consider:

```
unsigned int x = UINT_MAX;
unsigned int last_x = 0;

int dx = x - last_x;
```

Obviously the difference is `UINT_MAX`, but that doesn't fit in an int, so you get the (presumably undesirable) result of `-1`.

The only time this will work as intended is if `x` is part of a circular sequence (eg, a clock rolling over), in which case you should use

```
int dx = static_cast<int>(x - last_x);
```

But **not**

```
int dx = static_cast<int>(x) - static_cast<int>(last_x);
```

as that could cause signed integer overflow -  undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with `unsigned` integers, you will have to take precautions when subtracting to avoid negative results:

```
if (x > last_x)
{
  dx = x - last_x;
}
else
{
  dx = last_x - x;
}
```

As others have stated, a negative result would cause wrap-around.

**Edit 1:**
If you want `dx` to be the signed result, you should cast the other values to `signed int` before subtraction:
`dx = (signed int)x - (signed int) last_x;`